# PHP Parallel cURL 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, curl

I'm using parallel cURL to download webpages source code by URL faster then single curl, but sometimes i get random amount of 502 error. If i'm using single cURL instead of parallel, i get less 502. Any solution how can i fix this?

```
502 Bad Gateway
The server returned an invalid or incomplete response
```

**Tested with:**

1. Localhost - XAMPP - PHP Version 7.0.13
2. VPS - (LAMP) - PHP Version 7.0.25

**PHP**

```
    $curl_arr = array();
    $master = curl_multi_init();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++)
    {
        $random = rand(1,9999);

        $link = trim($urls[$i]);

        $link = $link."?".$random;

        $url = trim($link);
        $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36');
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

        curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
    }
    do 
    {
        curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
    } 
    while($running > 0);
```

Comment: Whats the memory limit, try increasing in php.ini

Comment: @AamirR Increased it to 512M from 128M, but i still get the errors.

Comment: you don't make it clear whether the 502 is returning from your server, or the target server you're fetching with curl. if it is the latter, the problem isn't with your curl code, the problem is with the target website, and only an admin of the website returning the 502 error can fix it.